# Is there a counterpart to @!method tag for class methods?

Tags: ruby, yard

Yard has a tag `@!method` to describe documentation for instance methods that are created dynamically. Is there a similar tag for class methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YARD provides `@!scope` tag to set scope of methods. So use `@!method` first and as subtag `@!scope` (http://rubydoc.info/docs/yard/file/docs/Tags.md#scope).